Error I Keep Getting That Says "FileNotFoundError"
I am coding a neural network as a project, and whenever I try to convert & print an image from the data into grayscale, I keep getting an annoying pop up. If anyone could help, it would be appreciated! :)
Code
Error Message
So far, I've searched the internet to see what could've solved this problem, and I've found nothing about it. I saw some things as putting an r before the path to make it a raw string, but that was about it.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I would recommend to add a condition to check the path:
if not os.path.exists(path):
  print(f"Directory {path} does not exist.")
  continue

And add try-except for this part in the loop:
img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(img_array, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

Because you work with a specific path it is most likely that something is missing in your environment.
Good luck
